# jquery-ui Dialog scrolling to bottom of page on click

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a asp.net page with a fair amount of stuff on it, that opens another page in jquery dialog iframe. the dialog is opened by the following

```
<a onclick="OpenDialog(params);return false;">click to open dialog<a/>

function OpenDialog(params){
    var url ='Detail.aspx?params;
    $('#frmDialog').attr('src', url);
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 500,
        width: 950,
        title: 'Details',
        modal: true,
        close: function(a,b){refreshPage();}
    });
    return false;
}
```

all is working perfectly fine other than **when the link is clicked, the 'parent' page jumps down around a screens height**, and you then have to scroll back up to the dialog - this is in IE 8 & 9 - seems to be fine in FF

using jquery :1.8.0
ui: 1.8.23

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ended up with editing the jquery-ui css and changing the **absolute** positioning to **fixed**..
serves my purpose.

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

to

```
.ui-dialog { position: fixed; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but is problematic when my dialog is larger than the window.

Comment: Doesn't work, especially when opened lower down on the screen, clicking on the dialog now pushes it to the top of the screen. Problem solved, new one created!